# What movie has an astral projection machine and a drug addict lead character?

Tags: story-identification, movie

I have partial memory of a science fiction movie in which:

1. The lead actor is a drug addict. Most probably crystal meth.
2. The drug dealer he buys from has sex with his girl friend in return for supplies.
3. There is also a machine that lets a person see events happening around him in his astral projection form. While the body is attached to the machine, the astral projection can roam freely and see what is happening around him/her.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Confirmed in a comment by OP: this is *[The Ghostmaker](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1462757/)* (aka *Box of Shadows*).

From the Wikipedia summary:

> A group of young college students find an old 15th-century coffin,
>   which is equipped with a part clockwork-mechanical/supernatural
>   contraption that enables contact with spirits and even allows one to
>   experience becoming a ghost for a period of time, whilst cheating
>   death's grasp.

This coffin is what allows them to astral project. The main character's name is Kyle, and he is indeed a meth addict; his girlfriend Julie becomes the object of lust for Kyle's friend Sutton during his projection sessions.